# Searching breed of this dog

Tags: dogs, outdoor

i am activly searching breed of this sand dog. I am applying couple pictures for additional help. He was very playfull and friendly oriented. Miss the chance to ask his owner for  he's dog name and breed, because tihs sand friend come fast and run away fast.

[Image 1](https://ibb.co/gMkuua)
[Image 2](https://ibb.co/k6WCfF)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pet breed questions don't work well here.  See [Should we discourage pet breed / species identification questions?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-discourage-pet-breed-species-identification-questions)

Comment: Q & A in this topic really help me to indentify the breed. What are you talking? After searching on internet and asking my friends, dogs seem to be swiss shepherd. Tnx to Christy B. and newuser101 for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be white German Shepherd, mix of, or shepherd/Samoyed mixed. Gorgeous dog, a man who lives a few doors down from me has a dog that looks similar whose mom was Samoyed and dad was German Shepherd.

Identifying dog breeds and mixed breed dogs are very difficult and my answer as well as others should be taken with caution. I'd hate for you to breed or conclude predisposed health problems based on my guess it anyone's for that matter. Even most vets offices take general guesses on paperwork "lab mix", "hound mix" etc...

You can buy a kit online for roughly $50-$60USD that will come with a pain free, mouth swabbing DNA kit for your dog, that you send off in a prepaid package. It will tell you the breed of dog up to either 4 or 5 breeds, if it's multigenerational mixed breeding.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Based on google images and my pics, seem to me it's white shepherd or mixed like samoyed. I will know for future for this useful kit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a white husky to me.